# ruby - bundle install/update too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I just installed RVM, Ruby, Rails etc. on my virtual ubuntu 12.04 32bit running in a virtualbox. Now I encounter the problem that for my first rails project `bundle install` or `bundle update` takes very long time. Even when I create a new project with rails (which includes `bundle install`).

I use only the standard gems:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

 gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
```

I tried bundle install without any gems but `gem 'rails', '3.2.12'`. After that I typed again `bundle install` with all gems in my gemfile. It took me 10 minutes to check for dependencies.  The output of --verbose is a mix of `HTTP success` and `HTTP redirection`.

Rails version: Rails 3.2.12

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386)

Rvm: rvm 1.18.18

bundle version: Bundler version 1.3.2

I already searched fot a solution, but nothing helped.

Comment: Turn your firewall back on.

Comment: 1. ensure there is no firewall or poxy involved 2.check your dns settings, i.e. setup googles dns server (8.8.8.8), please be sure to remove any search domains 3. try to use http:// instead of https://

Comment: you run an antivirus system on a linux server? Remove that and ensure that your software is up2date.

Comment: I mean the firewall/antivir on windows. Sometimes it blocks the internet traffic.

Comment: What version of RubyGems are you using? `gem -v`

Comment: Changing https to http in my Gemfile did the magic. Thanks reto. Before I have to create the project with rails new APP --skip-bundle Does anyone know whats the problem with https?

Comment: If you are using rubygems version 2.0.1, there was a bug regarding https. You should do gem --upgrade

Comment: I don't think its being slow but more like an error. If you run "bundle install --verbose" which would output more comments. It actually says "Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError: Could not verify the SSL certificate" and it is stuck after that. Without producing any error if ran without --verbose. At the end, they suggest that "Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.", though.

Answer (score 47):

**I want to warn: There is a security purpose for using https over http. Try at first the other answers mentioned in this thread.**

Changing `https` to `http` in my **Gemfile** did the magic. Before I have to create the project with `rails new APP --skip-bundle`

Comment: I had the same problem on OS X with Rails 4 beta 1 and Ruby 2 and this fixed it. Changing https to http increased the speed of "bundle install" around 5-fold - from painful (minutes) to great (< 20 seconds). The main slow-down seems to be "Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..........." part.

Comment: Why does SSL make Bundler so slow?

Comment: Half of my Gemfile was executed for 1 hour... After using this way, it took just 5 minutes... THANK YOU for saving my night! But I don't understand what the hack is wrong with Ubumntu and rubygems?

Comment: I don't think this is specific to Ubuntu or OS X as the same happens to me on Debian sid (unstable). Replacing https by http gives a super boost while running bundle for some reason...

Comment: @Nick and where do you change this (https -> http) ?

Comment: @Rogier in your Gemfile - first line

Comment: @init3, ouch :/ Thanks found it, never noticed it their … ;-)

Comment: @Rogier the first line in your Gemfile.After change this, I just need less than one mins to 'bundle install'. really thank this topic.

Comment: Given the high profile nature of rubygems.org this could be pretty dangerous. I'd say the only reason there hasn't been a high profile cache poisoning attack or similar yet is *because* gemfiles default to https. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559754/why-rails-gemfile-defaults-to-https-when-http-makes-bundler-so-much-faster

Comment: Possible reason why https is so slow is entropy exhaustion: https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-jruby/issues/11#issuecomment-142824699

Answer (score 16):

Bundler just [got an update](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/2481) of parallel processing of gems.

```
gem install bundler --pre
```

will solve the problem in the best possible way for now.

[Source](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2013/09/parallel-gem-installing-using-bundler/)

Comment: No good for me, `bundle update` takes hours on my machine (WSL2)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use multiple jobs, it may improve a little bit

```
  bundle install --jobs 8
```

Here is a [tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/parallel-gem-installing-using-bundler) about it

Answer (score 5):

Bundler v1.12.x was released in 2016 and caused some users to experience [slow bundle install issues](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4478#issuecomment-219263764).

> In this instance staying with v1.11.2 is the best option (it's fast) until a fix is released.

It's worth heading over to [Rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler/versions) to try different versions of the bundler gem.

Check existing bundler versions, uninstall existing version, install version 1.11.2 example:

```
gem list | grep bundler

gem uninstall bundler -v existing-version-number

gem install bundler -v 1.11.2
```

Comment: Looks like this is fixed now, that linked issue has been closed.

Answer (score 3):

A developer friendly method is to override the gem server with a faster alternative.

In our case, we can configure `http` as a mirror to address slow `https` connections:

```
bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.org http://rubygems.org
```

This allows you to keep original `Gemfile` configuration while still using faster `http` connections to fetch gems.

If you wanted to switch back to `https`:

```
bundle config --delete mirror.https://rubygems.org
```

`bundle config` has a default `--global` option. You can specify `--local` to limit configurations to local application folder.

Configuration is saved into global `~/.bundle/config` and local `.bundle/config`.

Comment: This will have the same security issues as other answers which suggest replacing https with http in the Gemfile, so be aware of the risk if you follow this.

Comment: @pjmorse you are invalidating all answers while not adding much value. As I have noted, https still remains https, http is used in the backend as a mirror. It is apparent that we are replacing https in action with http and so we should be in a trusted environment. All https mentions in files remain https so there is no security risk if code is moved somewhere else.

Comment: Your answer is a valid solution to the question - that's why I didn't downvote it - but if you are fetching gems over http you are increasing your risk, whether you change the protocol in your gemfile or change the mirror configuration. Devs who choose this strategy should do so with their eyes open.

Comment: I have actually upvoted your answer as a recent solution, but using encrypted gem transfer addresses very limited security risks. There is no reported attack vector using gem files modified on the way, in a man in the middle attack or similar. When the infrastructure or ISP is untrusted. All the http connections are insecure and the dev environment is under question. For example even the resource files and javascripts would be manipulated.

Answer (score 3):

If you're still seeing this issue with Bundler 1.12.5, you may want to [try updating the OpenSSL used by your Ruby](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4478#issuecomment-222156572).

For me this went like so:

```
pmorse$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.12.5
pmorse$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
pmorse$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
pmorse$ brew info openssl
openssl: stable 1.0.2h (bottled) [keg-only]
```

[... more `brew` output ...]

```
pmorse$ rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.2 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

[... lots of `rvm` output ...]

```
pmorse$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

This should make `bundle` quicker again without requiring you to go from `https` to `http`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be basic answer but try to install developer tools from the main Ruby site. I have had a similar problem and it did work. Sometimes simple solutions are the best!

Good luck!