# Why Rails Gemfile defaults to https when http makes bundler so much faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The default gems source for Rails in the gem file is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Changing that to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

makes bundle install much faster so I am trying to understand what is behind the decision of making https the default. Is there something that I need to be aware of?

Comment: the added security you get with HTTPS, for starters?

Comment: mine does not work after changing to http

Answer (score 5, accepted):

form [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/515):

> Switching to HTTP is dangerous. It opens you to MITM
>   attacks.  Switching to HTTP allows hostile parties to replace gem
>   contents with malicious contents. Switching to HTTP is not
>   recommended.

Comment: Thanks. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Using HTTP would leave your application and server vulnerable to exploits. Suppose someone poses as rubygems.org and has redirected some node on the internet to their servers, they would now be able to distribute fake gems to you with arbitrary code. HTTPS reduces the risk of such an attack by providing some form of domain validation and transport layer security.

Comment: this is only true if you actually CHECK the certificates. i think that is what they recently changed in rubygems.

Answer (score 1):

It's safer. The place you're installing Gems from might be a MITM attack as others have said. The big push I believe came after:

http://venturebeat.com/2013/01/30/rubygems-org-hacked-interrupting-heroku-services-and-putting-millions-of-sites-using-rails-at-risk/